# Bridged NIC Connection Issue

Tags: networking, windows-10, network-adapter

I have a Windows 10 Pro desktop with two NICs which are bridged. This configuration has been working fine until today.

The yellow warning triangle appeared in the system tray next to the netwok icon and I now have no internet access.

The Network & Sharing Centre says *"No network access"* and the network profile is set to Public.

Running ipconfig shows that the connection has picked up an APIPA address and the gateway address is blank.

I have unbridged the NICs and reset them as well as rebooting the router but still the issue persists.

I've run **netsh winsock reset** with no change.

Available wireless connections are also not displaying so I'm assuming whateve has killed the NICs has also affected the WiFi.

I've run Windows Defender and Malwarebytes Antimalware but neither have found anything.

Comment: Since it unexpectedly got an automatic address, are you sure your DHCP server is working correctly?

Comment: I have rebooted the router which is the DHCP server and there are also wireless devices in the house (including the laptop I'm currently posting on) which are connected with no issue.

Comment: I know the ports on the router are working as I have an Xbox plugged directly into it and Internet is available.

Comment: are there any warnings on the NICs in device manager?

Comment: Not for or any device, network-related or otherwise.

Comment: I've just been troubleshooting the rest of the network and it checks out so I know its the NICs on the desktop. I can't imagine for a second both of them have broken at the some time so I'm banking on something having messed with the configuration.

Comment: Okay...very weird...having unplugged everything back to the router and plugged it all back in again, on connecting both NICs all appears to be in working order!

Answer (score 0):

Unplugged all network devices back to the router and reconnected them one-by-one.

Strange but true!